# Is there an way read and append multiple yaml files with R?

Tags: r, dataframe, yaml

I am trying to read multiple YAML files in same directory with using for loop. Then I need append them to a dataframe.

Here is my code:

```
library(yaml)
library(reshape2)

test_path <- paste0(getwd(), "/tests/")

test_files <- list.files(path=test_path, pattern=".yml", all.files=FALSE, full.names=FALSE)
df <- data.frame()

for (test_file in test_files)

  out <- yaml.load_file(paste0(test_path, test_file))
  x <- melt(out)
  df <- x
```

This is the `out` parameter:

```
> out
$`Test-Scenario-1`
$`Test-Scenario-1`[[1]]
$`Test-Scenario-1`[[1]]$name
[1] "Example Test 1 hello"

$`Test-Scenario-1`[[1]]$description
[1] "low level load test"

$`Test-Scenario-1`[[1]]$url
[1] "https://www.github.com/"

$`Test-Scenario-1`[[1]]$typle
[1] "load"

$`Test-Scenario-1`[[1]]$thread
[1] 7

$`Test-Scenario-1`[[1]]$loop
[1] 10

$`Test-Scenario-1`[[1]]$head
NULL

$`Test-Scenario-1`[[1]]$delay
[1] 100
```

But I getting this error in `x <- melt(out)`, what exactly is the problem?

> "Error in names(object) <- nm :    'names' attribute [1] must be the
> same length as the vector [0]"

**Example YAML Files**

*hello_test.yml:*

```
Test-Scenario-1:

  - name: hello Example Test 1
    description: hello level load test
    url: https://www.hello.com/
    typle: load
    thread: 10
    loop: 20
    head: NO_HEAD
    delay: 100
  
Test-Scenario-2:

  - name: hello Example Test 2 
    description: hello level load test
    url: https://www.hello.com/
    typle: load
    thread: 10
    loop: 20
    head: NO_HEAD
    delay: 100
```

*example_test.yml:*

```
Test-Scenario-1:

  - name: Example Test 1
    description: low level load test
    url: https://www.github.com/
    typle: load
    thread: 7
    loop: 10
    head: NO_HEAD
    delay: 100
  
Test-Scenario-2:

  - name: Example Test 2
    description: low level load test
    url: https://www.github.com/
    typle: load
    thread: 7
    loop: 10
    head: NO_HEAD
    delay: 100
```

Comment: Possibly because you have a `NULL` in there. E.g., I can generate the same error using `out <- list(a=1, b=2, c=NULL)` then `melt(out)` . Since `unlist`ing with a `NULL` gives nothing for that value - `unlist(out)` - the length of the names of `out` doesn't match the length of the returned values.

Comment: I never thought, its fixed :) I changed the `NULL` value to `NO_HEAD`. @thelatemail

Comment: But it's shows last yaml file data in dataframe, other yaml file datas are missing. @thelatemail

Comment: You might have to provide a couple of small yaml example files. It's difficult to guess what might be happening without them.

Comment: I was added to end of the question. @thelatemail

Comment: Ah, I see, you're overwriting `df` each time through the loop. You need to grow your output, or even better, `lapply(test_files, function(x) do_the_loading_here )` and get all the output in one list.

Comment: This completely solved the problem, if you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as solved. @thelatemail